# Python multi processing start the script over again?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multi processing` in Python. The following is the demo of my code:

In function `main`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Main program starts here."

    SOME CODE....

    process_1 = Process(target=proc1,  args = (arg1, arg2))
    process_2 = Process(target=proc2,  args = (arg3, arg4))
    
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    
    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
```

And in function `proc1` and `proc2`:

```
def proc1(arg1, arg2):
    print "Proc1 starts from here."

    SOME CODE....
```

So what I expect to see as output is:

> Main program starts here.
>
> Proc1 starts from here.
>
> Proc2 starts from here.

However, what I got is:

> Main program starts here.
>
> Main program starts here.
>
> Main program starts here.

It seems that both the `proc1` and `proc2` start the `main` rather than the procs.

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Many thanks.

Comment: Works for me (on Linux, after changing `def __name__ == "__main__":` to `if __name__ == "__main__":`). Are you on windows?

Comment: Linux or Windows? Since your example has a syntax error, its not the real code. If you are on Windows and your real code doesn't nest the startup code in a `if __name__ == "__main__":`conditional, you'll get the output you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __name__ == "__main__":
```

Should be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

But if I execute your code with python 2.7 I get:

```
    def __name__ == "__main__":
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I rename `def` to `if`:

```
Main program starts here.
proc2
proc1
```

So I wonder how you get your code working (you probably modified it before pasting it here)

Comment: Wouldn't that be a syntax error, rather than causing bad guarding for the main process code?

Comment: Indeed on python 2.7(windows) I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yup, `def a == b:` is not a valid function header. If you like stuff like that, haskell.